# Power Query - replace multiple substrings in a string from a list

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

I have a column with phrases like, which I need to clean from chars like ;,:! etc, by replacing them with a space (to avoid concatenation of words).

**EXAMPLE OF INPUT AND OUTPUT:**

***"bla.blabla X&!:blablabla"***   needs to become ***"bla blabla X blablabla"***

And I am not finding an easy simple solution!

```
source = data,  //which has Oldcol column with data to clean
CharsToRemove = { ".", "'", ":", ";", "!", "?", "<", ">", "{", "}", "[", "]", "'", "`", "^", """", "&", "-","/", "\", "|","(", ")", "," , "=", "+"}, 
//line below is where I'd like to get to, it is not working
Newcol = Table.AddColumn(source , "NEWCOL", each 
             Text.Replace([Oldcol], CharsToRemove , " ") )
```

i'm looking for the last line to work, basically.

The option of nested replace statements works but it's bulky since the actual list of chars to replace is long, and it happens in numerous parts of the code. 
I can turn it into the function, but I would love to know if there is a way to avoid all that, and just have a smart line-line that does that job?

thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of M code that is not working, could you please post a data sample of the BEFORE and the AFTER mocked up manually?

Comment: is it better like this? example above the code.

Comment: So, why don't you just run a few replace statements over the column? One replace for each character you want to remove? Why fuff around with `List.Transform .... Character.FromNumber` etc, if it does not do what you want? What's the problem with creating 4 Replace statements, replacing one unwanted character at a time?

Comment: @teylin, the list of chars to remove is really long, i have multiple replace statements now.  But i need to do this in multiple places in the tool, and having 20 lines with replace everywhere is not great, do you see what i mean?

Comment: @teylyn i have replaced that list.transform with the actual chars - you can see it's not fab to have that many replace lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For multiple text replacements, you can use List.Accumulate, e.g.

```
let
    CharsToRemove = Text.ToList(".':;!?<>{}[]'`^""&-/\|(),=+"),
    Source = #table({"Oldcol"},{{"bla.blabla X&!:blablabla"}}),
    Cleaned = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Oldcol", each List.Accumulate(CharsToRemove,_,(String,Remove) => Text.Replace(String,Remove," "))}})
in
    Cleaned
```

Comment: Marcel, is it possible to pass a list of columns into this ?   I.e. 
.... =  Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{   {"Oldcol", "OtherCol"}, each .....

Comment: would you mind helping me understand the accumulate? I'm googling like mad but can't figure out the seed and accumulator.

Comment: Recently I published a video, explaining List.Accumulate as part of a series of videos about solving binary puzzles with Power Query:
https://youtu.be/1EjIhYVUQmk?list=PLmajzIMNl6yF3jRegPeByEYSS6J4OLMTb

Comment: #marcelbeug, Both of your answers solved my problem.  Except I needed a list of words not a symbol, so I created this step instead:  'WordsToRemove = {"stretch", "stretch-", " - stretch"},'

Answer (score 3):

For multiple columns, you can use Table.ReplaceValue.

```
let
    CharsToRemove = Text.ToList(".':;!?<>{}[]'`^""&-/\|(),=+"),
    Source = #table({"Oldcol1", "Oldcol2"},{{"bla.blabla X&!:blablabla","bla.blabla X&!:blablabla"}}),
    Cleaned = List.Accumulate(CharsToRemove,Source,(Table,Remove) => Table.ReplaceValue(Table,Remove," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Oldcol1","Oldcol2"}))
in
    Cleaned
```

Comment: This is a spectacular use of `List.Accumulate`! MSFT should really add this one to the docs to drive home the full range of the function usage cases allowed by `seed as any` parameter spec.